# Array into multiple arrays c++

Tags: c++

i have a string array which keeps data which read from a file.
it consists 76 lines.

what i want to do is store those in different arrays.
like from 21st line to 31st line in 1 array. and 31st to 41st one array. how can i do it... plz help

i want to split 70 lines into 7 arrays each containing 10 lines of it. and do it **without using vectors**

but this did not work

Comment: [Not this again.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: 7*10 != 77 .. What do you want to do ?

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector<std::vector<std::string<> > >` (or `std::map<std::map<std::string<> > >`) as your container? Either would make your life easier. And follow the link that @chris left you, it will save you a world of pain.

Comment: That last edits makes this a totally pointless question since you do not show anything useful (and your last sentence has a dangling reference).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the equality operator `==`. `i` will only be equal to one of those values *6 times* across the entire loop execution. Only when `i` is `11`, `22`, `33`, `44`, `55` or `66`; for any other value of `i` your loop will do *nothing*.

You probably meant `<` instead.

Comment: I was wondering why you deleted that comment. Looks like I should take notice.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
getline(ol, arr[i/11][i%11]);
```

where arr is a `std::vector` of `std::vector<std::string>`s. Or array of array of strings.

Still another way is:

```
while (1) {
  std::string *ptr;
  if (i < 11) ptr = arr1;
  else if (i < 22) ptr = arr2;
  // long list of arrays

  getline(ol, ptr[i%11]);
  // increment i, break on eof...
}
```

Comment: For some unknown reason, vectors are out.

Comment: i solved it my self. first initialize two variables in one loop,
eg: for(int i=start; j =0; i < end ; i++,j++)
so to start and end you can pass the values from the large array. j will be small array insexes. so it will be easy.  
arr1[j] = largearray[i];

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string arr[8][10];

    int i = 0, j = 0;

    ifstream ol("a.txt");

    while(getline(ol, arr[i][j]))
    {

        ++j;
        if(j == 10)
        {
            ++i;
            j = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

This is assuming you don't have more than 80 lines.